# javascript onclick button generates table of random arithmetic problems

Tags: javascript, math, button, random, onclick

I am a javascript novice. I've been trying to get through this assignment but just can't see where my mistakes are and it's due by midnight. Any help would be appreciated! These are the instructions:

Create web page which starts with a button that redirects to finished table.
The table generated is a 3 X 4 table and each cell is filled with a math problem.
The math problems will use random numbers between 1 and 20.
The problems will use one of the 4 operations: addition, subtraction,
multiplication, or division, generated at random, too. I must use the following functions:

function buildIt()

function buildTable(rows, cols)

function randOne()

function randTwo()

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Random Math Table Generator</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type = "text/javascript">
function buildIt()
{
//function to call buildTable setting the values for the //rows and columns the table
var rows; var cols; var i; var j; 
buildTable(rows, cols);
}
function buildTable(rows, cols)
{ 
//function to build actual table
//include for loop in which next two functions are called
document.write("<div id='content'><p>&nbsp;</p>");
document.write("<table width = '60%' border = '1' align = 'center' cellpadding = '5' cellspacing = '5'>");
ranNum = (rows + 1) * (cols + 1);
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
document.write("<tr>");
for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
{
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table> </div>");
}
function randOne(min, max)
{
//function to generate random number between 1 and 20
var randNumOne = return Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
var randNumTwo = return Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
}
function randTwo()
{
//function to generate the specified operations randomly
var cellContents;
switch(randOp){
case "+": answerNumb = randNumOne + randNumTwo; break;
case "-": answerNumb = randNumOne - randNumTwo; break;
case "÷": answerNumb = randNumOne / randNumTwo; break;
case "x": answerNumb = randNumOne * randNumTwo; break;
}
cellContents = randNumOne + operation + randNumTwo;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1 id="logo">Table Builder</h1>
<p><input type ="button" onclick="buildIt()" value = "Build a table"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The F12 key will typically open the developer console in most browsers. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

The below isn't answer but some tips that will help you out in this task and in future ones.

- Use document.createElement instead of document.write.
  HTML objects are much easier to manage than just printing text to the screen and hoping for the best.
  I.E:
  `var table = document.createElement('table');`
  `document.body.appendChild(table);`
- Use CSS for styling instead of HTML attributes.
  `table.style.width = "60%";`
  `table.style.border = "1px solid black";`
- To assign new value to a variable you do not need to redeclare it.
  `var randNumOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
  randNumOne = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)`

Another important concept is **Scoping**
When you write code inside { } you create a new code block.
Each code block has its own scope.
Code written outside of { } block is placed in the global scope.
If you declare a variable in Block 1 and then call a function that was not declared inside block 1. That variable will not be accessible in the function.

```
var test = 'outside';
function block1() {
  var test = 'inside block 1';
  var block3 = function() {
    alert(test);
  }
  block3(); // Will output inside block 1.
  block2(); // Will output outside.
}
function block2() {
  alert(test);
}
block1();
```

There are also various syntax errors in your code. @tieson-t already mentioned it but you can use the developer tools in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and even IE.

Glancing at your code I can see the following errors:
 * Using undefined variables (rows, cols, randOp...)
 * using reserved commands out of place (return)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll look over the code again. I am going to throw out my text book and buy the Definitive Guide to Javascript. Hopefully with time and use I'll eventually get it, but it sure is frustrating when something doesn't come easy.

Comment: Before you go throwing books and buying new ones I recommand on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: I used The Online Lint to find syntax error on line 42, but I'll try the developer tools.

Comment: @Eyal: Not w3schools! It's very basic and not up to date. Use the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's apply a standard indenting pattern to the code, which a lot of editors will do for you, and a bit of formatting:

```
function buildIt() {
    //function to call buildTable setting the values for the //rows and columns the table
    var rows; var cols; var i; var j; 
    buildTable(rows, cols);
}

function buildTable(rows, cols) { 
    //function to build actual table
    //include for loop in which next two functions are called
    document.write("<div id='content'><p>&nbsp;</p>");
    document.write("<table width='60%' border='1' align='center' " + 
                   "cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>");
    ranNum = (rows + 1) * (cols + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            document.write("</tr>");
        }
        document.write("</table> </div>");
    }

    function randOne(min, max) {
        //function to generate random number between 1 and 20
        var randNumOne = return Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        var randNumTwo = return Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
    }

    function randTwo() {
        //function to generate the specified operations randomly
        var cellContents;
        switch(randOp) {
          case "+": answerNumb = randNumOne + randNumTwo; break;
          case "-": answerNumb = randNumOne - randNumTwo; break;
          case "÷": answerNumb = randNumOne / randNumTwo; break;
          case "x": answerNumb = randNumOne * randNumTwo; break;
        }
        cellContents = randNumOne + operation + randNumTwo;
    }
}
```

So we can see that the variables `rows`, `cols`, `i` and `j` are currently contained inside the buildIt function. All `var` statements create variables inside a function (object) at the function level. These variables are only accessible inside the function, or by doing fName.varName.

Note also that a function usually acts something like a mathematical function. If I define a function `cosine`, I could write it like this:

```
function cosine(x) {
    var resultValue = Math.cos(x);
}
```

But although `resultValue` would contain the right value, it's just been left inside `cosine`. In order to get the value out again, we generally `return` something:

```
function cosine(x) {
    var resultValue = Math.cos(x);
    return resultValue;
}
```

So I would expect your code structure to be more like this:

```
function buildIt() {
    var rows = 3;
    var cols = 4;
    document.getElementById('gridDiv').innerHTML = buildTable(rows, cols);
}
```

Here, buildIt is calling buildTable, and passing the result to the innerHTML property of some div with id gridDiv. Then buildTable could just concern itself with constructing a string of HTML, and not also have responsibility for where to put it.

Since buildTable is then just making a string, I would make randOne return a number, and randTwo return a string:

```
function randOne() {
    //function to generate random number between 1 and 20
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
}
```

Note that `return` is the last statement executed within a function; the statement is `return someValue`, and then it stops processing the function.

So build up the string from a single random number to a string containing a mathematical statement, to the whole html table; looping over rows and columns to create cells and then rows and then the whole table, and passing this back out to be set in the right place.

My advice is to use jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com to write it, and to get the smallest function working how you want first. For example, open the Console (which is just an interactive javascript window) in one of those sites and paste in the randOne definition above, then call it by typing randOne().

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'll definitely check out the sites you mentioned. I reworked my code so functions works now. I should edit thread. I realized my first mistake was not closing out my comment. Something so simple that I overlooked.